# zeroes are recognized as NaN from pandas' isnull()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0.0]*5, index=pd.date_range('2020-10-02 10:00:00','2020-10-02 10:04:00', freq='60s'), columns=['col1'])
print(df)
```

out:

```
                     col1
2020-10-02 10:00:00   0.0
2020-10-02 10:01:00   0.0
2020-10-02 10:02:00   0.0
2020-10-02 10:03:00   0.0
2020-10-02 10:04:00   0.0
```

And then I use the following line of code:

```
print(df[df.isnull()])
```

Which results in the following:

```
                     col1
2020-10-02 10:00:00   NaN
2020-10-02 10:01:00   NaN
2020-10-02 10:02:00   NaN
2020-10-02 10:03:00   NaN
2020-10-02 10:04:00   NaN
```

I am confused since I expected to get an empty dataframe back, since none of the values is NaN. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need compare column for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print(df[df.col1.isnull()])
```

If need compare all columns need [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) or [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if all values per columns are `True` or at least one. If one column DataFrame like here output is same.

```
print(df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)])
```